# Kohana hMVC: is there a way to list all model instances?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

In Kohana, is there a way to output a list of all of the models that are currently instantiated?

Comment: Just curious as to why you would want to do that?

Comment: because your models and controllers can be instantiated from anywhere, as it is one of the selling points of hierarchical MVCs, you can instantiate a model from anywhere, but the instantiation appears to be calling a singleton: Some_Model::instance()->someMethod(); which means that, presumably, if i did that again elsewhere, it would be using the same instance. but I have no way of knowing how many "instances" of various things have occurred in our system. We have about 10 shared kohana libraries working together (as various application layers) -- it would be great to see the instances listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Kohana, but it can be done in native PHP:

**Code**

```
    $article = new Model_Article();
    $declared_classes = get_declared_classes();
    $target_parent_class = 'Model';
    foreach($declared_classes as $class){
        if(is_subclass_of($class,$target_parent_class))
            echo "$class is a subclass of $target_parent_class <br/>";
    }
```

**Output**

```
    Kohana_ORM is a subclass of Model
    ORM is a subclass of Model
    Model_Article is a subclass of Model
```

If you want to list down only the `Model_Article`, set `$target_parent_class = 'ORM';`

Comment: No, it won't work because kohana uses autoloading to load/instantiate the model as and when you need them (http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/autoloading). 

If you need to get a list of files in models directory (taking into account the Cascading File System), perhaps you can extract the relevant codes from http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Kohana_Core#find_file